# Особенности использования nvl и coalesce

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть два вроде бы похожих кода:

```
select coalesce(1,(select 100/0 from dual)) from dual;
```

и

```
select nvl(1,(select 100/0 from dual)) from dual;
```

Это две функции, для выполнения которых необходимо пройтись по всем параметрам, но `coalesce` отрабатывает без ошибки, а `nvl` ошибку выдает. Почему так?

Comment: Рекомендую поставить тег Oracle, потому как функция NVL не поддерживается более ни какими СУБД

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле, COALESCE «умнее». NVL обязательно расчитывает оба аргумента перед выдачей результата, а COALESCE расчитывает аргументы в порядке проверки. Стало быть, когда в nvl встречается ошибка, он ее выдаст. 
Для чего нужно это знать: когда мы в nvl запихиваем подзапрос, он обязательно отработается, в то время как coalesce может его пропустить
Источник: [тут](http://oraclemaniacs.blogspot.ru/2012/03/nvl-coalesce.html)